# Create a new table with first rows as the column names from old Table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

This very interesting problem is to create stored procedure to take parameters of table name oldTable and new table name newTable .
**The column names of newTable should be values of first row of oldTable** and rest of rows are content. 
So Far I have got success if I know the number of columns as devised inthe following query.
*This is required to import data from a tool but there is no option to select header row ,the columns are named as field_1,field_2 etc in this tool.*

```
--Following is a solution but does not work when number of columns vary :     
SELECT 'CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE AS SELECT ' || REGEXP_REPLACE(FIELD_0, '[^a-zA-Z'']') 
     || ',' || REGEXP_REPLACE(FIELD_1, '[^a-zA-Z'']') 
     || ',' ||REGEXP_REPLACE(FIELD_2, '[^a-zA-Z'']') 

     || ' FROM (SELECT ROWNUM  R,' 
           || 'FIELD_0 ' || REGEXP_REPLACE(FIELD_0, '[^a-zA-Z'']', '') 
           || ', FIELD_1 ' || REGEXP_REPLACE(FIELD_1, '[^a-zA-Z'']', '') 
           || ', FIELD_2 ' || REGEXP_REPLACE(FIELD_2, '[^a-zA-Z'']', '') 

           || ' FROM test) WHERE R <> 1'
      FROM oldTable
     WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Here the oldTable is structured as following

```
 CREATE TABLE oldTable 
   (    "FIELD_0" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "FIELD_1" VARCHAR2(30), 
    "FIELD_2" VARCHAR2(30)
   )  ;
insert into oldTable (FIELD_0, FIELD_1, FIELD_2)
values ('a', 'b', 'c');

insert into oldTable (FIELD_0, FIELD_1, FIELD_2)
values ('apple', 'ball', 'cat');

insert into oldTable (FIELD_0, FIELD_1, FIELD_2)
values ('1', '23', '4');

Old Table
            FIELD_0 FIELD_1 FIELD_2
        1   a       b       c
        2   apple   ball    cat
        3   1       23      4

NewTable (First row of old table is Column of new table)
                a       b       c
            1   apple   ball    cat
            2   1       23      4
```

I am trying to create a solution that works with any table with any number of columns,the solution should be useful to many people if there is one.

There could be solution if we could loop through values and columns as in given below.The only problem is to get the values of first row to construnct the dynamic query.

```
BEGIN
    FOR col IN (select column_name
                  from cols
                 where upper(table_name) = upper('oldTable')) LOOP

     --Some code here
    END LOOP;
  END;
```

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. You want to write a stored procedure to create a table called "NEWTABLE" based on "OLDTABLE" but it's not clear what the difference between them is. Could you just do `CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE AS SELECT * FROM OLDTABLE WHERE 1=0` to replicate the table's structure?

Comment: The column name of new table is rowvalues of old table, this is so because our import system does not have option to select header row.

Comment: Have I got this straight? you have an import system that inserts the contents of a file into a generic table.  The first row that is inserted contains the column names.  My feeling is that it might be better to create a view rather than duplicate the data.  However there are (at least) two problems.  1 - first row inserted is not necessarily first row retrieved by a query - is there some other way to ID the row of column names.  2 - how do you know the datatype of each column?

Comment: Yes Christian the system inserts contents of a file to a table,but the table is created on fly so the number of columns varies for different files. All data type are varchar of 32 size, First row is always header , as rows are inserted in order there wont be a issue with the first row.

Comment: View doesnot solve the problem because the problem of column name remains same in view.

Comment: Your first problem is determining which row contains the column headers. Is there a "row number" column being inserted?

Comment: Jeffrey its always the first row in the order of inserting without any ordering.select * from oldtable where rownum=1

Comment: ` its always the first row in the order of inserting without any ordering.` In other words, you hope it's the first row but you cannot guarantee it because OLD_TABLE has no sort key or other identifier. Queries without an ORDER BY column are returned in an undefined order, although most of the time you'll be lucky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced this problem in the past, and the only way I was able to solve it, is by using [DBMS_SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm). The below stored procedure can be adjusted as per your need. There are a lot of comments, read them carefully as they explain how this procedure works. I am assuming you are able to identify the first row that will be the columns names in the new table. :

```
PROCEDURE create_stg_tab(old_tab_name IN VARCHAR2, new_tab_name IN VARCHAR2)
IS
v_ct             number default 0;
v_col            varchar2(1000) default '';
l_theCursor      integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor; 
l_colCnt         number; 
l_descTbl        dbms_sql.desc_tab; 
l_columnValue    varchar2(4000); 
l_status         integer; 
v_dest_cols      varchar2(1000) default '';
v_sql            varchar2(1000) default '';
v_col_insert     varchar2(32000) default '';
v_sql_insert     varchar2(32000) default '';

BEGIN

--get the number of columns of the source table
select count(*) into v_ct from all_tab_cols where upper(table_name) = old_tab_name AND OWNER = <SCHEMA NAME>;

--build your dynamic source query
if v_ct > 0 then
    for i in (select column_name from all_tab_cols where table_name = old_tab_name AND OWNER = <SCHEMA NAME>)
    loop
        v_col := ltrim((v_col||','||i.column_name),',');
    end loop;

    --Get dynamic select all columns from old table
    v_sql := 'select '||v_col||' from '||old_tab_name;
    dbms_sql.parse(l_theCursor,v_sql,dbms_sql.native ); 
    dbms_sql.describe_columns( l_theCursor, l_colCnt, l_descTbl);

    for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop 
        dbms_sql.define_column(l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue, 4000); 
    end loop; 

    --execute cursor
    l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_theCursor); 

    --loop through the rows 
    while ( dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_theCursor) > 0 ) loop 
        --loop through the columns
        for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop 

            dbms_sql.column_value( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue ); 
            IF l_columnValue IS NOT NULL THEN
                --REGEXP_REPLACE start from inner most (You can customize/ignore this): 
                --1)if value is just a number, replace it with the source column name
                --2)if value starts with anything except letters (e.g. start with number but has letters), remove the leading non-letters
                --3)replace all non leading characters (except numbers and letters) with '_'
                --Ex.1289789bbB#4B$5 => bbB_4B5, 222 => source_column name
                v_dest_cols := v_dest_cols || (l_descTbl(i).col_name||' as '||substr(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_replace(REGEXP_REPLACE(l_columnValue,'^\d+$', l_descTbl(i).col_name, 1),'^[^a-z,A-Z]+', null, 1),'[^a-z,A-Z,0-9]', '_'),0,30))||',';
                v_col_insert := ltrim((v_col_insert||','||l_descTbl(i).col_name),',');
            END IF;
        end loop; 

        --remove last ','
        v_dest_cols := rtrim(v_dest_cols,',');
        --build create new empty table statement
        v_sql := 'create table '||new_tab_name||' as select '||v_dest_cols||' from '||old_tab_name||' where 1=2';
        --build insert into the new table statement
        v_sql_insert := 'insert into '||new_tab_name||' select '||v_col_insert||' from '||old_tab_name||' WHERE <condition to fetch rows from 2nd onwards>';
    end loop; 

    --execute
    execute immediate v_sql;
    execute immediate v_sql_insert;
end if;

exception
    --your exception
END create_stg_tab;
```